# Why UTF-8 takes more time in processing

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, utf-8

What is the reason of slow performance when dealing with utf-8

I had a Pandas code where I read from csv in chunk do some data transformation. My benchmark before assigning `encoding='utf-8'` was `29s` per 250k rows.

After I implemented enconding to `utf-8` to `read_csv` and `to_csv` it take double time i.e `60s` per 250k rows.

```
for df in pd.read_csv(downloaded_file, chunksize=chunksize, compression='gzip', low_memory=False,
                                  skipinitialspace=True, encoding='utf-8'):

# do some handling

df.to_csv(outfile_name, index=False, compression='gzip', sep='\t', quoting=1, encoding='utf-8')
```

My data processing is mainly renaming columns, detecting and removing blacklisted words, rounding the price etc.

Comment: Maybe because the conversion from utf8 encoded bytes to unicode strings takes some time...

Comment: sorry if its silly, Is utf8 encoded and unicode strings different ? if I am specifying `encode=utf-8`. Doesn't it means that all of my cells will be `unicode` strings ?

Comment: UTF-8 encoded and unicode strings are different in python. Each unicode character converts to two UTF-8 characters.

Comment: More exactly Python unicode strings contains unicode characters which can have any code up to U+1FFFFF (or depending on the Python version up to U+FFFF). For example, the unicode string `u'abéè'` can be expressed as `u'\x61\x62\u00e9\u00e8'` and is in utf8 `b'ab\xc3\xa9\xc3\xa8'` or `b'\x61\x62\xc3\xa9\xc3\xa8'`